# How do Menu Screens/Screen Changes work in C# and XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm working on a game in C# w/ XNA, and I want to make a main menu screen/title and options screens.

I'm not sure how to make them, or what's required to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Game State Management](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/samples/gamestatemanagement) sample.

Also, I'd recommend reading [this article](http://www.darklock.com/xna/?p=33) for a detailed explanation of how the sample mentioned above works.